# after successful installation of expo-cli. 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, reactjs, native, expo, yarnpkg

i installed yarn using `conda install -c conda-forge yarn` then i installed expo-cli using yarn `yarn global add expo-cli`. after successful installation i should be able to use `expo init` but 'expo' is not recognized as an internal or external command

[successful installation of expo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEsx1.png)

[expo not recognized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsuuc.png)

Comment: did you restart your terminal and/or computer?

Comment: Off course I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add expo cli and npm path to Environment Variable

> C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli

Comment: Shouldn't it add to the path automatically?

Comment: Sometimes it does add automatically sometimes not, this is crazy and i wasted almost 3 hours btw happy coding